# module hmrc client is not a registered callable error in a react native android app

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

- I am new to react-native and I am familiar to android native
- In android studio have added the bundle and running the code
- I am running a project getting the error in only `debug mode` (App
  installs and runs but soon, I open I get this error)
- In `release mode` there is no error

Debugging I tried:

- Deleted node modules and package.lock.json
- npm install

---

[image]